# Data not being passed from Razor page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor app that takes user input via a form field and puts it into a database.
However, the data is not being passed from the front end correctly:

Razor file

```
@using Blogs.Shared.Models
@page "/addpost"
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

    <h2>Create Post</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name" class="control-label">Titles</label>
                    <input for="Name" class="form-control" bind="@posts.title" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Address" class="control-label">Content</label>
                    <input for="Address" class="form-control" bind="@posts.content" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="@(async () => await tas())" value="Save" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="@Cancel" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @functions {

        public Posts posts = new();

        protected async Task tas()
        {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Posts/Create", posts);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/listposts");
        }

        void Cancel()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/listposts");
        }
    }
```

What I would expect this to do, is when `Save` is pressed, the data from Title and Content is assigned to `posts` and then passed to my POST method:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Blogs.Shared.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Blogs.Server.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDataAccessProvider _dataAccessProvider;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public PostsController(IDataAccessProvider dataAccessProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("PostsController");
            _dataAccessProvider = dataAccessProvider;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Posts/Create")]
        public void Create(Posts post)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical("Data 1", post);
            _logger.LogCritical("Data 2", post.content);
            _logger.LogCritical("Data 3", post.title);
            _dataAccessProvider.AddPosts(post);
        }
    }
}
```

All of my `_logger.LogCritical` lines just return blank, and when the write to the DB occurs it complains that `title` is empty (this field in my DB is set to NOT NULL).

Can anyone help as to why this is not working?

**EDIT**
I have updated the code to better match Antoine B's suggestions but its still  not working:

```
@page "/newpost"
@using Blogs.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>@Title Post</h1>
<hr />
<EditForm Model="@posts" OnValidSubmit="SaveUser">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Name" class="form-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="posts.title" />
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => posts.title)" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Address" class="form-label">Content</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="posts.content" />
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => posts.content)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light" @onclick="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
@code {
    protected string Title = "Add";
    protected Posts posts = new();

    protected async Task SaveUser()
    {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Posts/Create", posts);
        Cancel();
    }
    public void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/listposts");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the Posts entity defined? is the same entity?

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of the Posts before sending it to your API?

Answer (score 1):

To bind a value to an input component you must add an @ before the bind property, like following `@bind="posts.title"` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

That's what's not working for you.

I also don't recommend you to use the @functions because it is not recommended by Microsoft for razor files (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#functions)

```
@code {

    public Posts posts = new();

    protected async Task tas()
    {
        await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Posts/Create", posts);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/listposts");
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/listposts");
    }
    
}
```

I hope it helped you

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have made the suggested changes but the issue still remains. Is there a way I can see the content of `posts` before it is passed to `api/Posts/Create`, to try and identify where my issue is? I have updated my question with the changes.